# \allowbreak does not work in \index

Tags: indexing

I would like to include `\allowbreak` in an `\index` entry but I can't get it to work. The `\allowbreak` is changed to `\penalty \z@` in the .idx file, which corrupts the generated index.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `\protect\allowbreak`?

Comment: A small working example code would be helpful and instructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably calling `\index` in the argument to another command; here's an emulation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

a\index{abcdef@abc\allowbreak def}

% now do the call in the argument of a command
\textbf{g\index{ghijkl@ghi\allowbreak jkl}}

% now use the proper input
\textbf{m\index{mnopqr@mno\protect\allowbreak pqr}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

This produces the following `.idx` file

```
\indexentry{abcdef@abc\allowbreak def}{1}
\indexentry{ghijkl@ghi\penalty \z@ jkl}{1}
\indexentry{mnopqr@mno\allowbreak pqr}{1}
```

The same problem with `\allowbreak` turned into `\penalty \z@` would happen if you have something like

```
\newcommand{\indexword}[1]{#1\index{#1}}
```

and do

```
\indexword{abc\allowbreak def}
```

Using `\protect\allowbreak` will do also in this case. However, sorting of index entries with `\allowbreak` in them will probably give wrong results.